# Adding default role to newly registered user in VS Express 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am starting with the default created Register.aspx.cs with additions made to add in the FirstName and LastName of the user. This works fine.

I now want to be able to default any new users to a role of "User" so that they can only access appropriate pages. I see lots of posts on older versions of VS,,, but none seem to work here. I have added 2 roles to the AspNetRoles Table (Admin,User).

I am new to VS and C#, so likely am missing something simple.

Current Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Account
{
    public partial class Register : Page
    {
        protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = new UserManager();
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = UserName.Text,
                FirstName = FirstName.Text,
                LastName = LastName.Text
            };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the user's role when they sign in.

I am not for sure, but off of the top of my head I believe new users are by default assigned to no roles at all. So it should be easy to check what roles they are in, decide they are a new user, and then assign them to the roles you would like them to be in.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/assigning-roles-to-users-cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security; // Add this to import the namespace


Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName)
```

Comment: What I am really looking for is a way to add a role to the user in the if (result.Succeeded) section of code (or similar)... so that immediately after/during self registration the newly created User is added to the user role.

Comment: So after `IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);`, add your code to add the user to the roles you want. The code to do so uses the `Roles` class.

Comment: When I try to use Roles.AddUserToRole the system does not recognize this,,, so cannot use that...  This is what is so confusing for me, none of the solutions I can find online work Roles. returns an error "The type or namespace name 'Roles' could not be found".

Comment: Did you import the namespace into your file?

Comment: @BrentOliver I had that problem too when I started out and digging around the internet to find out which namespace to import is a PAIN! But it is `System.Web.Security`, and this really is how you do it, and I promise you all those other solutions you found really do work, it's just they omitted the part where they imported the appropriate namespaces.

Comment: Have no idea how to do that. I am starting with a new asp.net project,,, and first time I am trying to do the asp side,,, background is much more in database than asp.

Comment: @BrentOliver Up at the top of your .cs file, where it says `using System.Web;`, add a new line that says `using System.Web.Security;`

Comment: Closer... now getting error on run saying that rolemanager is not enable. When I look up how to do that and set it to enabled in the web.config,, still does not work, and the default web config says ASP.NET Membership role is disabled in this template.... looks like it is trying to force to use new Identity methods,,, or something. Very frustrating something so simple and basic is so difficult.

Comment: @BrentOliver Getting it all enabled and set up was quite frustrating, but it's a one-time thing. : (