# How to add roles to newly created users in ASP.NET using OWIN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

How can i set all new registered users by default to role "users"?

Here`s my code for registering new users:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>();
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
    var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);                            

    var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user already exists.");
        return View();
    }
    user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Username,Email = model.Email, };
    await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);           

    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412717/adding-default-role-to-newly-registered-user-in-vs-express-2013/31412950#31412950 Is this any use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
    roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("User"));
userManager.AddToRole(adminUser.Id, "User");
```

if for any reason `ID` dose not updated use this:

```
await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
    roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("User")); 
userManager.AddToRole(userManager.FindByName(user.UserName).Id,"User");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, there is another problem now im getting error when i set a role name, http://i.imgur.com/ErT0Uav.jpg

Comment: i found something and i think its working: 
 if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
            {
                var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "User";
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }

Comment: Ah thanks, i see you have helped again and thank you very much for your time .